# $_FILES not working and gives no errors

Tags: php, linux, apache, forms, http-post

this is my html page which includes form :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align:center;" >
        <form id="upload" action="file_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="12412412" /> 
            <label for="file">Dosya Adı:</label>
            <input type="file" mame="file" id="file"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Yükle"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my file_upload.php file :

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
</pre>

<?php
    if( $_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0 ){
        echo 'Error : ' . $_FILES["file"]["error"]. '<br/>';
    }
    else {
        echo "File : " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br/>";
        echo 'File Type : ' . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . '<br/>';
        echo 'File temp adr: : ' . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

my php info records :

```
file uploads : on
max file uploads : 20
upload max file size : 32M
post max size : 32M
```

and my tmp folders permission set to 777. i am working on mac os 10.9 on bitnami mamp stack 5.4.9

file_upload.php gives me this :

```
Array
(
)

File :
File Type :
File temp adr: :
```

i tried with and without `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="12412412" />`  in my html form. i search evry site on the internet and i can not find the problem.

Comment: What if you take fiddler (or any other http/network sniffer you like more) and see the real request?

Comment: You have wrong attribute, check my answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong attribute:

```
<input type="file" mame="file" id="file"/>
```

It should be `name`:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
```

Thats why `$_FILES` are empty; after fixing attribute `mame` to `name` it will work.

Comment: thanks a lot. my mistake.this is a good record for who trying to fix that kind problems.